# Changing Intel X710 fiber NIC speed

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet, 10gbit

I have a optical X710 NIC which runs in 10,000Mb/s speed (SFP+). I use `ethtool` to show its capabilities:

```
ethtool enp1s0f0
Settings for enp1s0f0:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full 
                            1000baseX/Full 
                            10000baseSR/Full 
                            10000baseLR/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
                            1000baseX/Full 
                            10000baseSR/Full 
                            10000baseLR/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: FIBRE
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

As you can see, 1GE is supported. But, when I try to change its speed, I get this error:

```
sudo ethtool -s enp1s0f0 speed 1000
Cannot set new settings: Operation not supported
  not setting speed
```

Do you have any idea about the problem? How can I change the speed mode?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Intel adapter guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19373/adapter-user-guide-for-intel-ethernet-adapters.html):

> Fiber-based adapters operate only in full duplex at their native speed. You cannot change the speed
> or duplex of Intel adapters that use fiber cabling

The NIC will autonegotiate settings with the link partner down to 1GB/s.